# seam removal after stitching image using frequency filter in python ( panorama)

Tags: python, image-processing

I am beginner in the programming filed. i am trying to remove seam using this document https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aidgu.jpg, can be found on this website https://isis.astrogeology.usgs.gov/fixit/projects/isis/wiki/The_Power_of_Spatial_Filters. I have used multiple opencv low pass (filter2D, blur,gaussianblur and mediunblur) and high pass (laplacial, soblex,sobely and dft) filter and combined them to check the different result, but I am not getting the desired result. I am attaching my code here.

Code:

```
    def seam(im1,im2,H):

#low pass frequency filter for stitched images. 
        low_pass=warpTwoImages(im1,im2,H)
        kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.float32)/25
        dst = cv2.filter2D(low_pass,-1,kernel)
        blur = cv2.blur(low_pass,(3,3))
        blur1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(low_pass,(3,3),0)
        median = cv2.medianBlur(low_pass,3)
        low_pass=[]
        low_pass.append(dst)
        low_pass.append(blur)
        low_pass.append(blur1)
        low_pass.append(median)

#high pass frequency filter for image 1 before stitching 
        high_pass1=[]
        laplacian1 = cv2.Laplacian(im1,cv2.CV_64F,ksize=3)
        high_pass1.append(laplacian1)
        sobelx1 = cv2.Sobel(im1,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=3)
        high_pass1.append(sobelx1)
        sobely1 = cv2.Sobel(im1,cv2.CV_64F,0,1,ksize=3)
        high_pass1.append(sobely1)

        rows, cols = im1.shape[:2]
        crow,ccol = rows/2 , cols/2
        mask1 = np.zeros((rows,cols,2),np.uint8)
        mask1[crow-30:crow+30, ccol-30:ccol+30] = 1
        dft1 = cv2.dft(np.float32(im1),flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
        dft_shift1 = np.fft.fftshift(dft1)
        fshift1 = dft_shift1*mask1
        f_ishift1 = np.fft.ifftshift(fshift1)
        img_back1 = cv2.idft(f_ishift1)
        img_back1 = cv2.magnitude(img_back1[:,:,0],img_back1[:,:,1])
        img_back1 = cv2.normalize(img_back1,np.ones(img_back1.shape), alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
        cv2.imwrite("imgback1.jpg",img_back1)
        high_pass1.append(img_back1)

#high pass frequency filter for image 2 before stitching 
        high_pass2=[]
        laplacian2 = cv2.Laplacian(im2,cv2.CV_64F,ksize=3)
        high_pass2.append(laplacian2)
        sobelx2 = cv2.Sobel(im2,cv2.CV_64F,1,0,ksize=3)
        high_pass2.append(sobelx2)
        sobely2 = cv2.Sobel(im2,cv2.CV_64F,0,1,ksize=3)
        high_pass2.append(sobely2)
        mask2 = np.zeros((rows,cols,2),np.uint8)
        mask2[crow-30:crow+30, ccol-30:ccol+30] = 1
        dft2 = cv2.dft(np.float32(im2),flags = cv2.DFT_COMPLEX_OUTPUT)
        dft_shift2 = np.fft.fftshift(dft2)
        fshift2 = dft_shift2*mask2
        f_ishift2 = np.fft.ifftshift(fshift2)
        img_back2 = cv2.idft(f_ishift2)
        img_back2 = cv2.magnitude(img_back2[:,:,0],img_back2[:,:,1])
        img_back2 = cv2.normalize(img_back2,np.ones(img_back2.shape), alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
        cv2.imwrite("imgback2.jpg",img_back2)
        high_pass2.append(img_back2)
        high_pass=[]

#stitching image1 and image2 after applying high frequency filter 
        low_pass=np.array(low_pass)
        for i in range(len(high_pass2)):
            result=warpTwoImages(high_pass1[i],high_pass2[i],H)
            high_pass.append(result)
        cv2.imwrite("vjvnvmn.jpg",result)

#combining images after applying filters. 
        high_pass=np.array(high_pass)    
        for x in range(len(low_pass)):
            for y in range(len(high_pass)):
                print " llllll"
                cv2.imwrite("%i__.jpg"%i,low_pass)
                cv2.imwrite("%i__.jpg"%i,high_pass)
                low_pass=low_pass.astype(high_pass[y].dtype)
                print low_pass[x].dtype,  "low", high_pass[y].dtype, " high"
                result=cv2.add(low_pass[x],high_pass[y])
                result = cv2.normalize(result,np.ones(result.shape), alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_32F)
                cv2.imwrite("%i_%i.jpg"%(x,y),result)
        return result
```

Input image https://i.stack.imgur.com/wc8oF.jpg
Output Images https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNQ0q.jpg
None of the filter is giving the desired output. I don't know where I am doing wrong. Please suggest a proper way to remove seam using frequency filter. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a tip you might want to insert some newlines and make it a little more readable

Comment: I have inserted new line to make it readable. Is it understandable now?? Thanks for the suggestion @everyone